# Limits problem to find the values of constants - a and b If $\lim_{x \to \infty}(1+\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x^2})^{2x}=e^2$ Find the value of $a$ and $b$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Problem :

If $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x^2}\right)^{2x}=e^2$ Find the value of $a$ and $b$.

Please suggest how to proceed this problem :

If we know that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left( 1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x= e$

Will this work somehow... please suggest

Comment: I don't think that the value of $b$ matters.

Answer (score 3):

Take logs of both sides to get

$$2 = \lim_{x \to \infty} 2 x \log{\left ( 1+ \frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{x^2}\right)}$$

Use $\log{(1+y)} \sim y - (y^2)/2$ as $y \to 0$ to get

$$2 = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left ( 2 a + \frac{2 b-a^2}{x}\right)$$

So we require $a=1$.  The value of $b$ is unimportant.

**ADDENDUM**

Details of the expansion of the log term to $O(1/x^2)$:

$$\begin{align}\log{\left ( 1+ \frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{x^2}\right)} &= \frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{x^2} - \frac12 \left ( \frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{x^2} \right )^2 + O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\\ &=  \frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{x^2} - \frac{a^2}{2 x^2} - \frac{a b}{x^3} - \frac{b^2}{2 x^4}+ O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\\ &= \frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{x^2} - \frac{a^2}{2 x^2} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) \end{align}$$

Comment: I think "$b$ can be any real number "would be a better statement.

Comment: @boywholived: why?  I mean, why can't $b$ be an imaginary number?

Comment: can we proceed this question in some other way... coz I didn't get the log part here please suggest.. thanks

Comment: I am afraid of something like this $b\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @sultan What he did is a series approximation of logarithm. Alternately you can try l'Hospitals rule after the substitution $t=\frac1x$.

Comment: @boywholived: a) you didn't answer my question, b) what you meant, I think, was any finite $b$, c) what is this $b \to \infty$?  $b$ is a constant!  It does not move.  $x$ will always end up larger.

Comment: Why do you use $\log(1+y)\sim y-(y^2)/2$ rather that $\log(1+y)\sim y$?

Comment: @Ilya: Because I expanded out to second order to demonstrate that the value of $b$ was unimportant.

Comment: @RonGordon: correct me if I'm wrong, but in your case $y = \frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{x^2}$, so you shall not lose $b$ anyway:
$$
  2x\log\left(1+\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x^2}\right)\sim 2x\left(\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x^2}\right) = 2a+ \frac{2b}{x}.
$$
In fact, in your case of the 2nd order approximation I'm not sure which $y = f(x)$ do you mean.

Comment: @Ilya: You're wrong.  If you are going to expand to $O(1/x^2)$, then you have to include the next term in the expansion of the log.  And $y$ is just a number, not a function of $x$.

Comment: @RonGordon: so the following argument is incorrect:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+a/x + b/x^2)}{a/x + b/x^2} = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\log(1+y)}{y} (=1)
$$
where we just made a change of variables under the limit?

Comment: @Ilya: that's not wrong, but it's a completely different statement - yours is less specific.  My argument concerns the specific behavior out to some asymptotic order, which has to be accounted for correctly.  Yours is just a limit statement, which may or may not be sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: @RonGordon: I think you can resolve my confusion if you could just elaborate in more details how do you apply $\log(1+y)\sim y-y^2/2$ to pass from the first equation in the answer to the second one.

Comment: @Ilya: see my post for the explanation.

Comment: @RonGordon: thanks for taking time to write it down. I'm still not convinced you need a 2nd order term, but you have a point. +1

Answer (score 2):

Alternative method:

The given limit is of the form : $ 1^\infty$

In general any limit of the form $ 1^\infty$ can be evaluated using the following theorem.
The statement is ::

$  if \lim\limits_{x\to a}{f(x)}^{g(x)}\ is\ of\ the\  form\ 1^\infty, $
$ the\ limit\ is\ equal\ to\  e^{\lim\limits_{x\to a}{(f(x)-1)*g(x)}} $

here $ f(x)\ is\ 1+\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x^2} $ and $ g(x)\ is\ {2x} $.

Substituting in the above expression, the limit is 
$ e^{{\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}}{(1+\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x^2}-1)}{2x}} $

that is,
$ e^{{\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}}{(\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x^2})}{2x}} $
then,

$ e^{{\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}}{({2a}+\frac{2b}{x})}} $
which finally is,

$ e^{2a}=e^2 $

which gives us a=1;

b is any real number and is immaterial.